# Flutter: Convert DateTime to Timestamp

Tags: firebase, flutter, datetime, dart, timestamp

I want to convert the DateTime value from the DatePicker to a Timestamp so Iam able to set it equal to a Timestamp from my Model to upload it to Firebase. Is there a way to upload this DateTime to my Firebase?

Answer (score 3):

```
Timestamp.fromDate(DateTime date)
```

Create a Timestamp from DateTime instance factory.

Found in the cloud_firestore package in pub, which you are probably already installing.

Comment: Than it just returns null but the DateTime is not null

Comment: If you can get a reproducible standalone case, please submit it as an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use default built-in get method of DateTime, as:

```
var timestamp = yourDateTime.millisecondsSinceEpoch
```

If you need this as seconds, not milliseconds, just divide by 1000 with flooring it:

```
var timestamp = (yourDateTime.millisecondsSinceEpoch / 1000).floor()
```

Also, according to [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp) of Timestamp,
you can use its factory as

```
Timestamp.fromDate(yourDateTime)
```

**UPD:** !millisecondsSinceEpoch!

Comment: The Method millisecondsFromEpoch is not available

Comment: I'm really sorry, my mistake. getter method 'millisecondsSinceEpoch'